# Benefit of App Links for deep linking

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, nsurlconnection, applinks

Recently facebook introduced Applinks (http://applinks.org/documentation/)
I am not able to understand the business benefit for this new way of deep linking, can someone explain it from that perspective

p.s. i am unable create applink in the tags